# Скрипт, удаляющий ненужные файлы из папки.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Опять вопрос: у меня в папке avatars собираются ненужные файлы, допустим, пользователь закачал фото, ему не понравилось, закачал другое. Первое фото ненужно и занимает место. Конечно, можно удалять вручную, но если таких пользователей много, это получается невозможным, тем более, что имена все кешированы. Есть ли такой php скрипт, который бы сравнивал имена фотографий в папке avatars с именами фото, которые записаны в базе, и удалял неисользуемые из папки avatars?

Comment: Есть но его нужно писать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При обновлении фотографии (юзер залил новую фотку) мы вынимаем адрес старого изображения из БД, удаляем через `unlink($file)` (будьте внимательны, адрес до файла в файловой системе может быть отличным от адреса до файла в адресной строке), адрес новой фотки записываем в БД.

Comment: Спасибо, все как всегда просто)

Comment: Выдается ошибка: Warning: unlink(avatars/): Permission denied in z:\home\localhost\www\spravmrakovo nov\www\spravmrakovo.ru\update.php on line 59. Написано, что отказано, может, просто права не те?

Comment: @Регина у вас же в ошибке явно видно, что unlink(avatars/) указана папка, а файла нет.

Comment: Точно, сама сейчас только поняла, вечно ошибки глупые делаю).

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
function clear() {
if (file_exists('/cache/'))
foreach (glob('/cache/*') as $file)
unlink($file);}
```